# Merge earlier Mercurial changeset with tip

Tags: mercurial, merge

I have a local Mercurial project. The tip revision is 562.

In revision 549 I made changes to 4 files in the project. These files have also had other changes made to them from revisions 550 through 562.

How can I compare and merge revision 562 (tip) with the changes made in revision 549? Basically I want to add back the code I deleted in revision 549 to the tip.

Also, I've got WinMerge configured as my external diff tool, so I'd like to be able to interactively merge instead of letting mercurial do it automatically. My merge command is `hg winmerge`.

Comment: ‘Add back the code I deleted in revision 549 to the tip’ — sounds like `backout`, no?

Comment: @Helgi That's exactly what I was looking for! If you put that in an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Basically I want to add back the code I deleted in revision 549 to the tip.

In Mercurial, this can be done using `hg backout` (see the [man page](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hg.1.html#backout)). This operation applies the inverse of the specified revision to the current repository state.